# VBScript Nothing returns garbage

Tags: vbscript

We have to use VBScript as an embedded script engine in our Hospital Information System.
When we use nothing to set the value of a control (textbox/checkbox/...) it worked always fine. Since somepoint it sets now the textbox to "?>".

```
item("TEXTBOX").value = nothing ' Leads to -> "?>"
```

It is not completly clear what causes this, maybe a windows update is responsible, every rollup ~ since KB3212646 Win7 2017-01 seems to cause this error.

My Question is now, has someone else also seem this error, so that it is clear that MS causes this error or is our HIS publisher responsible for not handling nothing correct.

I know setting a textbox to Nothing is not *best practice* instead "" should be better, but since the item object could be more the just a textbox e.g. a combobox/checkbox this seems, *from an objectoriented perpsective*, better. Or am I completly wrong?

Comment: Could you please add more details: on what platform is your HIS build? What is your purpose in setting item value to nothing?

Comment: Going out on a limb, since your code snippet doesn't show too much context. The keyword `Nothing` is for explicitly releasing objects, and it requires using the `Set` keyword as well. Using it on the `Value` property of a text box doesn't make any sense. For resetting such a value an empty string or maybe the `Empty` keyword would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Ansgar comment, you should apparently change everywhere you have `= nothing` to `= ""`

in your example

```
item("TEXTBOX").value = ""
```

Beware to keep the `nothing` if you have the `Set` keyword in left

```
Set some_object = Nothing
```